# Is there any jquery plugin for facebook like button in a lightbox

Tags: facebook, jquery, like

I am trying to find a plug-in for showing like our web site on facebook message for new visitors of my web page.

[image]

Is there any jquery based plugins for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any [lightbox plugin](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) will do the job, the content in the box you show is a [standard facebook Like button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) with pictures (you just have to play with their generator settings).

This tutorial from line25 "[How To Add a Custom Facebook Like Box to Your Site](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-add-a-custom-facebook-like-box-to-your-site)" walks you through it.

Answer (score 0):

Fancybox v2 is pretty nice http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ You will probably have to use the `inline` or `ajax` method so that when the modal opens Facebook can get the current URL for the like button. I'd first try using `inline` with fancybox